# Can someone explains the meaning of this expression ? 寄せ集めの色が濃い

Tags: meaning, expressions, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

A general said this comment about a bandit he just fought:

**黄巾賊は、数は多いが寄せ集めの色が濃い。首脳部はそうではないかもしれんが**

I can only understand vaguely that he might be saying the bandits though having a large number of troops, but they're for the most part not well trained soldiers.

Hope someone can correct my understanding if i was wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your understanding is correct.

寄せ集め means something like a "jumble", but with the implication that the quality is bad. Large in quantity, low in quality. That's what 寄せ集め insinuates.

寄せ集めの色 is referring to the masses of 黄巾賊, those who identifies themselves by wearing a yellow band(黄巾). So the 色 here is just 黄色, a symbolic reference to the rebel army.

Comment: "something like a "jumble", but with the implication that the quality is bad." - "hodge-podge", perhaps?